# Using Telemetry auto instrumentation with Python Flask app, how to avoid calling FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app) manually?

Tags: python, flask, open-telemetry

I'm learning telemetry auto instrumentation with a Python Flask-based app. The issue is my app will not generate traces unless I call FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app) manually.

I assumed that auto_instrumentation/sitecustomize.py will somehow do that but it doesn't seem to work that way.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import (
    SimpleSpanProcessor,
)
from opentelemetry.exporter.zipkin.json import ZipkinExporter
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.flask import FlaskInstrumentor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.requests import RequestsInstrumentor
PORT = 8000
MESSAGE = "Hello, world!\n"

app = Flask(__name__)

# create a ZipkinExporter
zipkin_exporter = ZipkinExporter(
)

trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(
    SimpleSpanProcessor(zipkin_exporter)
)


FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    result = MESSAGE.encode("utf-8")
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=PORT)
```

Packages:

```
opentelemetry-api==1.2.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.2.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask==0.21b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.21b0
opentelemetry-distro==0.21b0
opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin==1.2.0
```

Command I used: "opentelemetry-instrument python3 ./server.py"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/blob/main/instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask/src/opentelemetry/instrumentation/flask/__init__.py` suggests doing just that.

Unfortunately, `https://opentelemetry-python-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/instrumentation/flask/flask.html` is broken as of this moment.

Comment: Thank you! BTW I've just updated my example code with the actual code I'm using. Do you think I'm using auto instrumentation in a correct way? (I don't like the code to set up zipkin_exporter and  FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app) but I haven't found a way to  replace them with config keys/env vars).

Comment: Sorry. I don't have a good answer for that.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I've found out the root cause for my issue. It is because I ran Flask in debug mode. It is tracked by this issue https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/477 . It worked after I making the change as described here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/tree/main/docs/examples/auto-instrumentation#instrumentation-while-debugging